# How to create a new activity and then display text in it with android programming

Tags: android

I managed to have a button and then when I click on it, I go to a new activity that is called "TUTORIALONE"

and then I want to display some text in this new activity

so I have something like this

```
   Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent("my.android.TUTORIALONE"));
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
                    tv.setText("this is some text);

        }
    });
```

the problem is that it first displays the text on my button, and then it shows me the new activity, how would I achieve displaying the text on the new activity?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `TUTORIALONE` activity you probably have an associated xml file for displaying content. Perhaps it iss set something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.id.TUTORIALONE);
}
```

In the layout xml file for `TUTORIALONE` just add something like this

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
```

**EDIT**

To change the text of this `TextView`, do something like this in your `TUTORIALONE` activity.

```
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("this string is set dynamically from java code");
}
```

Note that the id here (R.id.text) is the same as in the xml file ("@+id/text")

Comment: how would I change the textView dynamically though?

Comment: @JohnJohn please see my edit on how to change the text of the textview at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate() of the new Activity, you can create a Button, set the text and then call setContentView() in order to show it.

In case you want to show to this Activity a string from the current Activity, you can pass this String an an Intent extra and then recover it to the new Activity.

Hope this helps!